# HAPI to NHAPI code conversion

Tags: xml, hapi, nhapi

I am supposed to convert HL7 message to XML format using NHApi in (C#, .net).
I somehow understood this code which does the same using HApi in Java.
I want the same code for NHApi in C#,.net

```
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.DefaultHapiContext;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.HL7Exception;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.HapiContext;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.Message;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v22.message.ADT_A01;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v22.segment.MSH;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.EncodingNotSupportedException;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.Parser;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.XMLParser;
/**
public class ExampleParseMessages {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws HL7Exception {

    String msg = "MSH|^~\\&|HIS|RIH|EKG|EKG|199904140038||ADT^A01||P|2.2\r"
            + .......";

     HapiContext context = new DefaultHapiContext();

     Parser p = context.getGenericParser();

     Message hapiMsg;

     try{
     hapiMsg=p.parse(msg);
     }
     catch(EncodingNotSupportedException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     return;
     }
     catch(HL7Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     return;
     }
     ADT_A01 adtMsg = (ADT_A01)hapiMsg;
     MSH msh = adtMsg.getMSH();
     String msgType = msh.getMessageType().getMessageType().getValue();
     String msgTrigger=msh.getMessageType().getTriggerEvent().getValue();

     System.out.println(msgType + " " + msgTrigger);

    XMLParser parser = context.getXMLParser();
    String encodedMessage =parser.encode(adtMsg);
    System.out.println("Printing XML Encoded Message:");
    System.out.println(encodedMessage);

   }
}
```

I want to turn this code to NHAPI code in c#.net. 
but cant find the replacement for the code snippet:`XMLParser parser = context.getXMLParser();
        String encodedMessage =parser.encode(adtMsg);`
Please help.
Any help is appreciated.